# SIGSEGV crash on MagicalRecord MR_contextWillSave:

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I have an app in TestFlight that keeps crashing on the first core data save. I've never been able to recreate the issue myself, but It is happening multiple times to multiple users. Im getting a set of taxonomy from our server as JSON then saving the results to core data like so:

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
                                    [self createRestrictions:restrictions inContext:localContext];
                                } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                                    if(success){
                                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                                            DLog(@"got and saved all restrictions");
                                            if(complete){
                                                complete(YES);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }else{
                                        TFLog(@"error saving restrictions: %@", error);
                                        if(failure){
                                            failure(@"Error saving restrictions");
                                        }
                                    }
                                }];





-(void)createRestrictions:(NSArray *)restrictions
                inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    for(NSDictionary *_restriction in restrictions){
        Restriction *restriction = [Restriction MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"tid"
                                                              withValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[_restriction[@"tid"] intValue]]
                                                              inContext:context];
        if(!restriction){
            restriction = [Restriction MR_createInContext:context];
            restriction.tid = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[_restriction[@"tid"] intValue]];
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the crash log from TestFlight[image]